# <stddef.h> std::ptrdiff_t' has not been declared

Tags: c++, std, qnx, ptrdiff-t

I have made my own source file, and I'm trying to add stddef.h. At compiling I have the following error:

> std::ptrdiff_t' has not been declared.

What I've done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried including [`<cstddef>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef) instead?

Comment: C headers don't populate the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg , yes, i've tried to include cstddef, but - I need libraries in my project from matlab simulink coder, which requires stddef.h....

Comment: Using smartphone, It took me 5 seconds to google it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t  just include <cstddef>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the standard ***C*** header, not the standard C++ header.

The standard C header will not put their symbols in the `std` namespace, since C doesn't have such things.

That you have other applications requiring the C header doesn't matter, if you want to use the `ptrdiff_t` type-alias from the C++ `std` namespace, you must include `<cstddef>`.

Or stop using `std::ptrdiff_t` and user the unqualified and global `ptrdiff_t` from `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: @infernalcucumber Yes.

Comment: I know, I'm newbie at programing, but do you mean that if I'll include <cstddef>, it should work properly with libraries which are requiring stddef.h ?

Comment: I've include <cstddef> instead of <stddef.h>, but when i've include libraries generated from matlab simulink coder, at compiling I have following error again:
'std::ptrdiff_t' has not been declared                                               line 72, external location: D:\QNX650\target\qnx6\usr\include\stddef.h